# How to speed up cloud run deployment by using cached docker image

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am using google cloud run to deploy my application. Every time I deploy the application, the build takes about 22 mins since  dlib library (one of the required libraries) is very large. I end up getting something like this:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib, face-recognition-models
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): still running...
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): still running...
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): still running...
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): still running...
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): still running...
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): still running...
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): still running...
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): still running...
```

Is there a way to cache the docker image so that I can speed up the build? Whenever I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` locally, it is very fast because pip has the libraries in its cache. I have the docker image of previous builds saved in the Artifact Registry.

Comment: How are you building the image? If you're letting `gcloud run deploy` do it, I don't think it supports caching but if you're building locally or explicitly calling Cloud Build, there are options.

Comment: Include enough details to reproduce this issue (Dockerfile, requirements.txt, etc). Note: Cloud Build does not cache Python dependencies for your build process.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options to speedup the builds by storing cached layers, mostly depends on the way you approach: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/speeding-up-builds